# How to set up a VSTO 4.0 prerequisite?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, vsto, windows-installer

We are using Windows Installer / MSI *not* ClickOnce.

We have followed this detailed Microsoft article on creating a Windows Installer for our
VSTO Outlook Addin:

[Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

It's fine, but always with these long, complex, detailed scripted setup instructions there's the problem of knowing what is safe to customise to fit our own circumstances.

In our cases we're using VS2010 and VSTO4 and the instructions are for VSTO3. So the launcher we created using those instructions complains about the missing VSTO3.

What do we have to change? And what do we insert for VSTO4? Here are the relevant extracts from the article:

> ```
> 6. In the Properties window, perform the following tasks.
>    a) Set the value of (Name) to Search for VSTO 3.0 Runtime.
>    b) Change the value of Property to VSTORUNTIME.
>    c) Set the value of RegKey to Software\Microsoft\vsto runtime Setup\v9.0.21022
>    d) Leave the Root property set to vsdrrHKLM.
>    e) Change the Value property to Install.
>
> 7. In the Launch Conditions(ExcelAddInSetup) editor, select the Condition1 launch condition, right-click the condition and select Properties Window.
>
> 8. In the Properties window, perform the following tasks.
>    a) Set (Name) to Verify VSTO 3.0 Runtime availability.
>    b) Change the value of the Condition property to the following VSTORUNTIME = "#1"
>    c) Leave the InstallURL property blank.
>    d) Change the value of the Message property to The Visual Studio Tools for Office 3.0 Runtime is not installed. Please run Setup.exe.
> ```

It's this last error (our *own* launch condition error, if you like) which is firing on the target machine.

> The Visual Studio Tools for Office 3.0 Runtime is not installed.
> Please run Setup.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there's an updated guide here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx

The same instructions, but updated for VSTO4.